# Android MediaPlayer is micro pausing every 20 seconds

Tags: android, nativescript, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play audio via a url but Android MediaPlayer is micro pausing every 20 seconds. I've tried multiple internet connections and the issue is pretty consistent. Local files do not have this issue. I've tested this issue on a Pixel 7 Pro. I've had reports of this happening on other Pixel devices but can't confirm if it's only Pixel phones. Interestingly I can't see an issue on any Pixel phones over at app-live.browserstack.com. I've tried wifi only and mobile data only.

`OnBufferingUpdateListener` returns 100% before 20 seconds.

`OnInfoListener` returns the following every 20 seconds causing a micro pause:

- `MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH`
- `MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START`
- `MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH`
- `MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END`

When I say micro pause I mean a noticeable ~100ms-500ms pause between an auto pause and play state.

Can anyone help me work out why this might be happening and how I can mitigate the issue?

Below is some NativeScript (javascript) code. It can be read as pseudo code for java:

```
const player = new android.media.MediaPlayer();

player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener({
    onBufferingUpdate: function(mp, percent) {
        console.log("Buffering " + percent + "%");
    }
}));

player.setOnInfoListener(
    new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener({
        onInfo: (player: any, info: number, extra: number) => {

            const MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH = 703;
            if (info === MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH) {
                console.log("MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH: Network bandwidth is " + extra + " bits per second.");
            }

            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_UNKNOWN) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_UNKNOWN: Unspecified media player info.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING: The video is too complex for the decoder: it can't decode frames fast enough.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START: MediaPlayer just started rendering the first frame of the video.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START: MediaPlayer buffering has started or paused after a seek. Playback should pause.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END: MediaPlayer buffering has ended. Playback should resume.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BAD_INTERLEAVING) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_BAD_INTERLEAVING: Media has not been properly interleaved or interleaved at all.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_NOT_SEEKABLE) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_NOT_SEEKABLE: Media does not support seeking.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE: New metadata is available.");
            }

            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_UNSUPPORTED_SUBTITLE) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_UNSUPPORTED_SUBTITLE: Subtitle track is not supported.");
            }
            if (info === android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_SUBTITLE_TIMED_OUT) {
                console.log(info, "MEDIA_INFO_SUBTITLE_TIMED_OUT: Reading the subtitle track takes too long.");
            }

            return false;
        }
    })
);


player.reset();
player.setDataSource('https://myaudio.com/audio.mp3');
player.setAudioStreamType(android.media.AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.prepareAsync();

setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('test 2');
    player.start();
}, 5000);
```